# Select multiple Dom elements by their CSS classes

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am using ExtJS 6.2.0 to select dom elements by their CSS classes (meaning all the mentioned classes should be styling the element to be selected) like so :

```
Ext.select('.x-btn-button .headerButtonsCls').removeCls("theme");
```

But it's not working.

How to do it properly instead ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Ext.select('.x-btn-button.headerButtonsCls').each(item => {
    item.removeCls('theme');
});
```

Comment: ok and how to get also the child of the item ?

Comment: Under the dom element selected (here `item`) i have a `span` tag which i also want to target how to do that ?

Comment: You can use item.select('span') which will return an array of found elements..

Comment: Nice, Clean, Neat and Sweet of you !